# pod scheduling not allowing pod to schedule to a free node

Tags: kubernetes, scheduling, replicaset

I have 3 environments consisting of a GKE cluster with 1 node pool with 5 nodes (autoscaling from 1-5) and using the same stateful set deployment. 2 of the environments are having no issues, the 5 pods/replicas scale just fine onto each node so 1 pod per a node. The resource limits and requests are exactly the same across all environments and the infra is deployed via reusable terraform modules etc. so there is no human error happening here as all objects involved are exactly the same.

The environment affected is basically not allowing the pod to go to the node because of not enough cpu, even though there is and again, the 2 other environments are having no issues with the same setup.

Also, there is literally nothing else deployed on the cluster/node pool so the only thing taking up resources will be the default kube-system workloads and my stateful set deployment.

Any ideas what is going on? If the issue had been happening on all 3 environments, it would be fine but the fact it is only happening on 1 of the 3 environments is very weird.

Comment: Most probably the node you are thinking of is free,  has a taint that stops your pods to deploy on them. The error of not having enough CPU is not coming from that node as if a node has taint kube-admn look for other possible nodes to deploy your pod. So other available options may not have enough CPU. Look for the node and check if it has any taint

Comment: Verify that your project has sufficient Compute Engine quota for GKE to scale up your cluster. And check Connectivity issues of your cluster

Comment: thanks both for the replies. the node which isn't taking on the pod has no taints to it. the node pool is set to scale from 1-5 nodes and there are currently 5 nodes running, the 4 other pods/replicas are able to schedule fine to the other nodes in the same pool and the 2 other clusters are able to schedule 5 pods/replicas across all 5 nodes without issues, it is just the one environment (which is setup exactly the same way) showing this very random issue

Comment: btw, each cluster is in a different gcp project too

Comment: [check your pod logs](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/docs/solutions/gke/using-logs) then you will be able to  find the exact error for pods not getting created on your node which will help us in troubleshooting issue